# try/exception for integer or double or string

Tags: java, string, integer, double

How to differentiate the integer and double. Example if i wanted to get integer and verify it. if it is integer then output "YOU are correct" else "You entred wrong. try again".

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class InputExceptions {

    private static int inputInt;
    private static double inputDouble;

    public static int inputInt() {

        boolean inputOK = false;
        while (inputOK == false) {
            inputInt = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Integer"));

            try {

                inputOK = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"*** ERROR: VALUE ENTERED NOT INTEGER ***");

            }

        } return inputInt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"*** INTEGER is correct Input: " + inputInt() + " ***");

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `inputInt = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Integer"));` inside the `try` block?

Comment: Yes I got this now. thanks alot man.....